# Why does my heat pump "blow" at warm (even hot) outdoor temperatures? Should not it be inactive?

Tags: heating, cooling, heat-pump, radiant-heating

We have a `Hoval UltraSource B compact C (8,11/200)` air/water heat pump in our house. I have noticed in warm weather that occasionally my heat pump "blows" outside.

I then thought that my heat pump cools in warm weather and found with [a web search that this is not possible for me](https://www.hoval.de/de_DE/K%C3%BChlen-mit-W%C3%A4rmepumpe:-die-nachhaltige-Alternative-zur-Klimaanlage/kuehlen-mit-waermepumpe).

German

> Bitte beachten Sie: Klassische Heizkörper können für eine Kühlung mit Wärmepumpe nicht verwendet werden.

Translation:

> Please note: Classical radiators cannot be used for cooling with heat pump.

What "magical" things does my heat pump do even though there is no need to heat at these temperatures?

The heat pump is also responsible for heating hot water (also a feature), is that the reason for the blowing?

Comment: While "classical radiators" can't be used for cooling (they would drip water due to condensing humidity) presumably a standard "fan coil unit" (a device which is designed to take chilled water, and has provisions for handling the condensation dripping) **could** be attached to it, if you wanted cooling. At least based on the wording of the translation...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The heat pump is also responsible for heating hot water (also a feature), is that the reason for the blowing?

Yes, hot water in a the tank (which is well above ambient temperatures) will slowly cool down and needs to be reheated periodically. If you use hot water then it also needs to heat the cold water replacing the hot water you used.